# Odd behavior with Objective-C switch statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, switch-statement

I have a game that uses a global integer `position` to navigate around the options menu. When the back button is pressed for every screen, it calls a function, `[self options]`, to reload the original "options" screen. I have a feeling that this is something extremely silly I messed up.

Now, the code that calls the function that determines whether or not the back button is this:

```
if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"back"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    // stuff should happen here
                }
```

With `touchIsInNode:` being my own custom method for handling taps returning a `BOOL` value (`YES` if it was).

Naming the buttons for the back buttons for each screen `backa`, `backb`, `backc`, etc. is a viable workaround, but it still calls the code in each switch case regardless of the value of `position`.

Here's what I have going on in my `switch` statement:

```
switch (position) {
            // case 0 thru 3 are unrelated to the question... 0 is for the main menu, 1 is for the original logic for the "options" screen, 2 is for the end of the game, and 3 is to skip to the end of the intro screen.
            case 4:
            {
                NSLog(@"position: %i", position);
                if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"backa"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    NSLog(@"store back button was pressed and [self options] is being called...");
                    [self options];
                }
                // store UI
            }
            case 5:
            {
                NSLog(@"position: %i", position);
                if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"backb"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    NSLog(@"stats back button was pressed and [self options] is being called...");
                    [self options];
                }
                // stats UI
            }
            case 6:
            {
                NSLog(@"position: %i", position);
                if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"backc"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    NSLog(@"about back button was pressed and [self options] is being called...");
                    [self options];
                }
                // about UI
            }
            case 7:
            {
                NSLog(@"position: %i", position);
                if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"backe"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    NSLog(@"dev options back button was pressed and [self options] is being called...");
                    [self options];
                }
                // dev options UI
            }
            case 8:
            {
                NSLog(@"position: %i", position);
                if ([self touchIsInNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"backd"] touchPoint:touchPoint]) {
                    NSLog(@"purchased options back button was pressed and [self options] is being pressed...");
                    [self options];
                }
                // purchased options UI
            }
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"INVALID POSITION: %i", position);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

My `options` method looks like this:

```
for (SKNode* node in [self children]) {
    // fade out and remove each node if it is not "optionsButton"
    if (![node.name isEqual:@"optionsButton"]) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:1] completion:^{
            [node removeFromParent];
        }];
    } else {
        // if it is "optionsButton", perform an animation.
        [node runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:1]];
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height - ((node.frame.size.height * (4.0 / 3.0)) / node.yScale)) duration:1] completion:^{
            // afterwards, call a method that logs each node's name.
            [self logEveryNode];
        }];
    }
}
position = 1;
NSLog(@"position: %i", position);

// processing labels

// add in each child

NSLog(@"options called, with %i nodes in [self children]", [self children].count);

// fade in all of the labels
```

Then, for each submenu in the options menu, they look like this (using the "store" one as a model):

```
position = 4;
for (SKNode* node in [self children]) {
    if ([node.name isEqual:@"optionsButton"]) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:(2.0 / 3.0) duration:1]];
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height - (node.frame.size.height * (1.0 / 3.0))) duration:1]];
    } else if ([node.name isEqual:@"store"]) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:1.5 duration:1]];
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height - node.frame.size.height * 3) duration:1]];
    } else {
        [node runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:1] completion:^{
            [node removeFromParent];
        }];
    }
}

// draw UI for the store and move the back button accordingly

SKLabelNode *back = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Cochin"];
back.alpha = 0;
back.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
back.text = @"back";
back.name = @"backa";
back.fontSize = 44;
back.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height * 0.5);

[self addChild:back];

[back runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:1]];
```

The result of this code is, each case is executed, even after `position`'s value has changed to `1` to signify going back to the `options` menu. Also, `didBeginTouches` is oddly called 5 times although I only "tapped" the screen once in the simulator. Here are the more relevant parts of what I have for a log:

```
2015-05-23 01:10:40.581 game[25258:1981445] position: 4
2015-05-23 01:10:40.581 game[25258:1981445] store back button was pressed and [self options] is being called...
2015-05-23 01:10:40.582 game[25258:1981445] position: 1
2015-05-23 01:10:40.588 game[25258:1981445] options called, with 10 nodes in [self children]
2015-05-23 01:10:40.588 game[25258:1981445] position: 1
2015-05-23 01:10:40.588 game[25258:1981445] position: 1
2015-05-23 01:10:40.588 game[25258:1981445] position: 1
2015-05-23 01:10:40.589 game[25258:1981445] position: 1
2015-05-23 01:10:40.589 game[25258:1981445] INVALID POSITION: 1
```

Why does every `case` run, even the `default` case? It seems like only `position == 4` should run `case 4` and something like `position == 500` would run the `default` case. If it helps, there are 5 sub-menus in the options menu.

Comment: case statements need to end with  `break;` or they will continue in the next case. Standard C behavior.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for not having `break;` there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a break statement to the end of each case block.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer when Stack Overflow lets me. Thank you to both you and Gerd K in the comments for finding this out!